# Jasmine Expect toMatch and Parentheses

Tags: regex, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, protractor

I noticed that when I formulate a Jasmine Expect using `toMatch` and the string that is being match contains `(` it will fail. Has anyone else noticed this? If so what did you do?

Example

This fails or returns "False" when it should return "True"

```
expect("test (test) with other stuff").toMatch("test (test)");
```

This passes and returns "True"

```
expect("test %test% with other stuff").toMatch("test %test%");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`toMatch()` is used for regular expression matches. Parenthesis have a *special meaning* (they are used for capturing/saving groups) in regular expressions, you need to escape them if you want them to be treated as normal parenthesis:

```
expect("test (test) with other stuff").toMatch("test \(test\)");
```